# transparent gradient for bottom ListView Item

Tags: flutter

I have got a Stack with three childs: `header` positioned on top, a `ListView` with multiple items and a `menu` that sticks on the bottom. This works well but i want the items behind the bottom menu to get a linear gradient transparency - similar to snapchat. I tried to wrap a ShaderMask widget above my ListView but this transparency is not fixed at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Here is some code:

```dart
ShaderMask(
            shaderCallback: (rect) {
              return LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
              ).createShader(rect);
            },
            blendMode: BlendMode.dstATop,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 15.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(15, 20, 70, 1.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
                      topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children:
                      sessions,
                  )
                ),
              ]
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `ShaderMask` is applied to the entire child, which in your case is the `ListView`. You could wrap your menu in another `Stack` and put a `LinearGradient` behind it using a `Container` with `decoration`, and you'll need to avoid gestures on that `Container` so you can still interact with the `ListView` if you tap on the `LinearGradient`.

You could do something like this:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Header(...),
    ListView(...),
    Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        IgnorePointer(
          child: Container(
            height: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Menu(...)
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: thanks man. I had to wrap a positioned widget around the second Stack but now it works great